# Using an array as an argument in a dblink connection query results in error message:

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, arguments, dblink

I'm using Postgresql 8.4 and I am writing a series of functions where I want to be able to pass in an array of integers, which I want evaluated by the dblink connection query. The function looks like this:

```
--======= Create a function that accepts an array of Top(n) Books and outputs the results to a temp table =======--

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_weblog_facts_dblink(VARIADIC l_spids integer[])
    RETURNS setof weblog_fact AS

$BODY$
DECLARE 
    rec weblog_fact%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=weblog_db port=5432 host=111.111.111.001 user=db_dev password=*****',
    'SELECT         
        id_hash,        
        logfile_id_hash,        
        logentry_timestamp,     
        ip,     
        method,     
        uri,        
        status_code,        
        bytes_transfered,       
        time_taken,     
        referrer,       
        user_agent_type_id,     
        special_id,     
        content_title_id,       
        content_release_id,     
        asset_type_id,      
        encode_type_id,     
        licensor_id,        
        broker_id,      
        campaign_id,        
        subsidized,     
        country_code3,      
        city,       
        postal_code,        
        longitude,      
        latitude,       
        language_id,        
        user_id,        
        tag,        
        app_id,     
        app_seconds,        
        app_cached,     
        cdn_id,     
        resource_name
        FROM weblog_fact WHERE special_id = any(' || array_to_string(l_spids, ',') || ')' )
AS weblog(
    id_hash character varying(40),
    logfile_id_hash character varying(40),
    logentry_timestamp timestamp(6) with time zone,     
    ip cidr,        
    method character varying,       
    uri character varying,      
    status_code integer,        
    bytes_transfered bigint,        
    time_taken bigint,      
    referrer character varying,     
    user_agent_type_id integer,     
    special_id bigint,      
    content_title_id bigint,        
    content_release_id bigint,      
    asset_type_id integer,      
    encode_type_id integer,     
    licensor_id integer,        
    broker_id integer,      
    campaign_id integer,        
    subsidized boolean,     
    country_code3 character(3),     
    city character varying,     
    postal_code character varying,      
    longitude character varying,        
    latitude character varying,     
    language_id character varying,      
    user_id integer,        
    tag character varying(64),      
    app_id integer,     
    app_seconds bigint,     
    app_cached boolean,     
    cdn_id integer,     
    resource_name character varying ) 
    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT rec;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN ;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

But when I run this:

```
SELECT * FROM get_weblog_facts_dblink (array[159783,157885,159301,159923,157952,159280,157454,157245,159831,157822])
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  function get_weblog_facts_dblink(integer[]) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM get_weblog_facts_dblink (array[159783,157885,1...
                  ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function get_weblog_facts_dblink(integer[]) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 15
```

This is my first attempt at a function that accepts an array as an argument, and I realize I'm complicating the issue with the dblink. The dblink select statement as a stand-alone works, but I change the `special_id = all(VARIADIC)` to `special_id IN (12345,12346,13456) )`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't to use plpgsql variables to dblink inside string literal - PL/pgSQL doesn't know a variable expansion inside strings like perl or php does. Second problem should be a keyword "VARIADIC" - so rename this parameter.

try to modify code:

```
dblink(...,
       'SELECT ... FROM weblog_fact 
          WHERE special_id = any(' || array_to_string(_variadic, ',') || ')'
      ) 
AS weblog(...
```

you can use a RETURN QUERY statement instead FOR LOOP RETURN NEXT

Comment: I thought VARIADIC was the keyword that allowed for any number of arguments to be passed. Using the function definition and the same call to it, I now get this error: `ERROR:  function get_weblog_facts(integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 2: SELECT * FROM get_weblog_facts(159783,157885,159301,159923,1...
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********`

Comment: Okay, I figured out I have been calling the function wrong. I use this: `
SELECT * FROM get_weblog_facts (array[159783,157885,159301,159923,157952,159280,157454,157245,159831,157822])` and at least I get the function to start up. I don't have a connection to the database anymore, so I'll need to look into that. Thanks for you help so far, Pavel.

Comment: Why do you have the comma following _variadic, and then again quoted ',' ? Is there supposed to be an empty argument after _variadic?

Comment: @JonMitten: that's the second parameter for the function `array_to_string()`, a quoted `,` used as delimiter in the resulting string. Read the [manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).

Comment: you have to use a correct variadic parameter too

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(VARIADIC paramname int[])
    ...
    RAISE NOTICE '%', string_to_array(paramname, '|');

Comment: I've updated the function with your suggestions, but still get an error - this time it's `ERROR: function get_weblog_facts_dblink(integer[]) does not exist`